# Display (print) string multiple times (repeatedly)

Tags: python

I want to print a character or string like '-' n number of times.

Can I do it without using a loop?.. Is there a function like

```
print('-',3)
```

..which would mean printing the `-` 3 times, like this:

```
---
```

Comment: See also: [Repeat string to certain length](/q/3391076/)

Answer (score 226, accepted):

Python 2.x:

```
print '-' * 3
```

Python 3.x:

```
print('-' * 3)
```

Comment: This is mentioned in the Built-in Types section of the docs (and should be mentioned in the official tutorial) http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-buffer-xrange

Comment: this is the correct bookmark in the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange

Comment: (seems they added -bytearray- in the bookmark name)

Comment: Is there a way to do this with f-string?

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer is short and sweet, but here is an alternate syntax allowing to provide a separator in Python 3.x.

```
print(*3*('-',), sep='_')
```

Comment: This will fail if we separate using  '\'  Check this : `*3*('-',), sep='\'`

Comment: @RushabhPatel This is because '\' is not a valid string, use '\\' instead or r'\'

Comment: @OlivierMelançon: `r'\'` is not a valid string literal → `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal`

Comment: @martineau You are right, then it should have been '\\'