# How can I write abreast in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

My code:

```
print "*" 
print "*"
```

Output:

```
*
*
```

But what I want is:

```
* *
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python print on same line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598181/python-print-on-same-line)

Answer (score 4):

Put commas at the end of first `print` statement:

```
print '*',
print '*'
```

Output:

```
* *
```

You can do `help('print')`.

Comment: Thank you for comma. It run like I want to

Comment: @OnurVarsak good! use help() ... it is really handy

Answer (score 0):

To simply avoid adding a newline, do as @LetzerWille instructs; add a comma.

To print the same character/string multiple times on a line, do

```
print('* ' * 2)
```

See: [Python display string multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/963161/python-display-string-multiple-times/963166#963166)