# (python) How to convert number into symbol ' * '

Tags: python

I just thinking how to convert the numbers into the ' * ' (eg. if I enter 4 then **** and the result will be like this: ****, ***, **, *)
I know that the code should be like this:

```
number = int(input())
while number >= 0:
    print (number)
    number = number - 1
```

but how to make it become ' * '?
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python display string multiple times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/963161/python-display-string-multiple-times), [In Python, how do I create a string of n characters in one line of code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424005/in-python-how-do-i-create-a-string-of-n-characters-in-one-line-of-code)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
print(number * '*')
```

It will print `*` number times. Example:

```
>>> print(4 * '*')
'****'
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach:

```
''.join('*' for _ in range(4))
```

However, as @GingerPlusPlus points out, this approach is slower than the other one overloading the `*` operator.

Comment: On my machine, it's almost 80x slower than `'*' * 4`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to print the astericks `*` symbol X amount times based on the number entered and then you want to count down to 1? That explanation might be rough, so here's an example of what I believe you are asking for:

If the user enters 3, you want to print:

```
***
**
*
```

If that is correct then here's a possible implementation (coded for Python 3.x):

```
number = int(input())

while (number > 0):
    print( '*' * number)
    number -= 1
# End While
```