# adding * in a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm completely new to programming and to python. I'm using python 3.9 at the moment, trying to go through a simple python tutorial, but one of the tasks gives me problems.

Im supposed to get an output like this: (after asking the user up to which number he wants to go)

```
1*
2**
3***
4****
5*****
6******
7*******
```

My code looks like this at the moment:

```
usercount = int(input("Up to what number do you want to go?"))

for x in range(usercount):
    print(x+1, "*")
```

and the output looks like that:

```
1*
2*
3*
4*
5*
6*
7*
```

What do I have to do?

Thank you.

Comment: You have to add more stars. The Python way is `(x+1)*"*"`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiplying a string with a number in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536996/multiplying-a-string-with-a-number-in-python)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display string multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/963161/display-string-multiple-times)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to print n start where n is the current number. To do something n times you would use a for loop.

In the example above you were using just a single `print("*")` which prints just a single start. To print more you would either print stars in inner loop, or create a single string containing stars:

```py
for x in range(usercount):
    print(x+1, end="") # end="" means that print won't end in new line
    for i in range(x+1):
        print("*", end="")
    print() # just add a new line at the end
```

Or by creating a star string:

```py
for x in range(usercount):
    stars = "*" * (x+1)
    print(x+1, stars)
```

Also to avoid typing x+1, you can specify the range to be `range(1, usercount+1)`

Answer (score 2):

This would work, but lots of different ways of making it work:

```
usercount = int(input("Up to what number do you want to go?"))
stars = ''
for x in range(usercount):
    stars += '*'
    print((str(x+1))+stars)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can multiply a string by an integer to reproduce the string N times. For example:

```
IN: 'ab' * 3
OUT: 'ababab'
```

In your case, you want to multiply the string `'*'` based on the iteration number. Watch out, python `range` starts at `0` and ends at `usercount-1`.

Answer (score 1):

use `enumerate`:

```
usercount = int(input("Up to what number do you want to go? "))

for i in range(usercount):
    print(str(i+1) + (i+1) * "*")

# output 
1*
2**
3***
4****
5*****
6******
7*******
```

Comment: No reason to use enumerate. i and x are equal because he used a for loop on a range..

Comment: oops, I mistakenly posted my draft answer instead of updated one. edited. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you are only printing `*` in `print(x+1, "*")`. You should multiply `*` with number of times you want to print it. Eg:

```
1* '*' = *
2* '*' = **
```

etc

Try,

```
usercount = int(input("Up to what number do you want to go?"))

for x in range(1,usercount+1):
    print(x, x*"*")
```

Answer (score 1):

Should another loop for `*`, two ways to go

1. duplicate string by times a number.
2. another inner loop to print how many `*`, but you have to specified option `end` to empty string for method `print` if no newline required for each print.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
In [1687]: usercount = int(input("Up to what number do you want to go?"))

In [1697]: for i in range(1, usercount + 1):
      ...:     print(str(i) + ("*" * i))
      ...: 
1*
2**
3***
4****
5*****
```

Comment: Numbers are not printed before the stars

Comment: @pjk Sorry. Updated my solution. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @pjk: Can you please retract your downvote?

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this;

```
usercount = int(input("Up to what number do you want to go? "))
stars = '*'
for i in range(usercount):
    print(str(i+1)+stars)
    stars += '*'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this one?
The algorithm is the same as previous answer.
This just has less code

```
result = "\n".join([f"{i}{'*'*i}" for i in range(1, 8)])
print(result)
```